# Was the import button removed from the parse dashboard data browser?

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform

I'm trying to import data to an app database that I exported from a different apps database.

While I was researching how to do this, I found an answer that suggested using the import button in the data browser. I think this will work but I can't seem to find the import button.

Either I'm crazy or they removed it. Does anyone have any info on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new version of Parse Dashboard have the Import Data button removed. If you want to use the Import button you can use the old version of dashboard.

The old version

https://www.parse.com/apps/(ProjectName)

Comment: As of a week ago, the Import button is no longer available in the old version either.

Comment: First I thought, their sync and migration process will work better if no one imports large data sets via CSV, but then yet again, we can still do this programmatically, so I don't get it. :(

Comment: Please update the answer, it is confirmed that the old version does not have the import button either

Answer (score 4):

This morning, the button as disappeared from my dashboard. I am working on the older version, not the beta one. Guessing Parse is slowly pushing us off the cliff.

Comment: Yup. They've removed it even from the old dashboard